# Jekyll stopped working after update

Tags: jekyll

I have updated my jekyll to 2.4.0 then it stopped working. Look below:

```
D:\blog>jekyll server -w
Configuration file: D:/blog/_config.yml
            Source: D:/blog
       Destination: D:/blog/_site
      Generating...
                    done.

D:\blog>
```

After the generating it stops.

Comment: No error message ? Try `jekyll build --trace`, maybe we'll have more clues to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to call `jekyll serve`, not `jekyll server`.